# IIS Threads Per Processor Max

Tags: asp, threads, iis

We have IIS 7 running a classic ASP app. We noticed that while the CPU stays low, the ASP Request Queue can sometimes get high, causing slow response times. After some research it seems changing the max threads per processor setting may be in order.

Until now it was at the default of 25, and we have 6 cores, so 150 threads max. Before changing anything, I noticed that w3wp.exe is always using 150 threads, which seems to suggest more threads may indeed help us.

So we tried changing the value from 25 to 50, and stopped and restarted the server instance, but when looking at the thread count, it still sits at 150.

I would be very surprised if we now have a 300 thread max (50*6 cores) but we *happen* to just be using 150, the old max. It seems much more likely that the old max is still in place.

Any ideas as to how to make sure the setting is really in effect?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599939/increase-number-of-threads-per-worker-process-iis or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293865/iis7-increase-number-of-threads-concurrent-requests-per-working-process for an answer (can not enter it as double).

Comment: I've seen those, and I've set those settings. The first link is what applies to me, the second seems to apply to .NET, in either case, the change made no difference in regards to ACTUAL threads used and hence the question above.

I've seen a few questions similar to this on other forums but none had an answer.